# exportfs: internal: no supported addresses in nfs_client

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs

I am trying to set up a NFS server on an AWS instance running SLES11.

After installing nfs-utils, I tried to export a test share.  Here is what my /etc/exports file looks like:

```
/opt/share1 ec2-50-16-224-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com(rw,async)
```

export -ar returns the following message:

```
exportfs: internal: no supported addresses in nfs_client
domU-12-31-38-04-7E-02.compute-1.internal:/opt/share1: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what the no supported addresses error means? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I've just had exactly the same problem and it was just a simple matter of starting the nfs service in order to fix it.

Comment: Way to go, Phil. Eazy peazy. BTW don't forget to `chkconfig nfs on` (for RHEL 6), or `systemctl enable nfs` for RHEL 7, and later Fedora revisions and its ilk, or similar in your brand/distro.

Comment: To add a note: the chkconfig command above wasn't enough in my case, I also had to run 

    "sudo service rpcbind restart"

Answer (score 3):

```
[root@stormking ~]# uname -a
Linux stormking 2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 18:16:18 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@stormking ~]# service nfs reload
exportfs: internal: no supported addresses in nfs_client
exportfs: stormking:/export/oradata01: No such file or directory


[root@stormking ~]# service nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
[root@stormking ~]# service nfs reload
(no error)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I saw these errors, I don't think I'd pay any attention to the *no supported addresses* error until the other error (*No such file or directory*) was resolved. Often times, error messages like this come about because one program generated an error, then prints out the actual error from the system - that is, one of the errors is an obtuse repeating of the other.

If you fix the *No such file or directory* error, I would suggest that the other error would vanish as well. It also states that the error is "internal" which suggests that the true error is the following one.